# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16777216 bytes)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, macos-mojave

I ran **composer install** on my `16 GB` Mac Book Pro, and I got this

```
 ⚡️  distributor-portal  composer install                                                                                                       
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                      
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16777216 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16777216 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 220

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.⚡️  distributor-portal
```

---

**which php**

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php
```

**php --version**

```
PHP 7.1.4 (cli) (built: May  6 2017 10:02:00) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

**cd /usr/local/; ls -lrt**

```
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root   wheel    26B Jan 23  2017 openssl@ -> mac-dev-env/openssl-1.1.0c
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root   wheel    37B Jul  5  2017 php5@ -> /usr/local/php5-7.1.4-20170506-100436
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root   wheel    30B Oct  9  2017 mysql@ -> mysql-5.7.19-macos10.12-x86_64
-rw-r--r--    1 root   wheel     0B Dec 12 14:47 .com.apple.installer.keep
drwxr-xr-x@  10 root   wheel   320B Dec 12 15:51 ../
drwxr-xr-x    3 root   wheel    96B Dec 12 15:52 mac-dev-env/
drwxr-xr-x    3 root   wheel    96B Dec 12 15:53 remotedesktop/
drwxr-xr-x   21 root   wheel   672B Dec 12 15:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x   15 bheng  admin   480B Dec 12 15:53 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   14 501    wheel   448B Dec 12 15:54 packager/
drwxr-xr-x   25 bheng  admin   800B Dec 12 15:54 share/
drwxr-xr-x   14 root   wheel   448B Dec 12 15:54 php5-7.1.4-20170506-100436/
drwxr-xr-x   71 bheng  admin   2.2K Dec 12 15:54 Cellar/
drwxr-xr-x   11 bheng  admin   352B Dec 12 15:54 var/
drwxr-xr-x  396 bheng  admin    12K Dec 12 15:54 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   13 bheng  admin   416B Dec 12 15:54 php5-5.6.14-20151002-085853/
drwxr-xr-x   80 bheng  admin   2.5K Dec 12 15:54 opt/
drwxr-xr-x   13 root   wheel   416B Dec 12 15:54 mysql-5.7.19-macos10.12-x86_64/
drwxr-xr-x   17 bheng  admin   544B Dec 12 15:54 Homebrew/
drwxr-xr-x  122 bheng  admin   3.8K Dec 12 15:54 include/
drwxr-xr-x  231 bheng  admin   7.2K Dec 12 15:54 lib/
```

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: check are you push `composer.lock` in server

Comment: How do I check that ? What is that for anyway ?

Comment: see in server `composer.lock` exist or not

Comment: Yes, it is exist with a lot of codes. like 4905 lines of code ![](https://i.imgur.com/acGgPeu.png)

Comment: try `composer install  --no-dev`

Comment: @Davit Same result ‍♂️ : https://i.imgur.com/CUgwJ6i.png

Comment: That case I can not help. Sorry

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your machine might have 16GB installed but PHP is not configured to use it. Locate your php.ini file (on OSX with PHP installed by Homebrew its at `/usr/local/etc/php/$PHP_VERSION/php.ini`. Open it with an editor and search for `memory_limit`. There you specify how much memory a PHP process can use. If you like to give it *all* change the value to `-1`.

`$PHP_VERSION` is the version of your PHP installation. To figure out which is installed use `php --version`.

Comment: How you know I used php 7.2 ? Is it just a sample for me to follow ?

Comment: While this answer will get you moving forward you should locate the root cause of the mem leak.

Comment: php version show version `7`, which php show version `5`, how do I know which PHP ini I should update ?‍♂️ : https://i.imgur.com/Aorry2N.png

Comment: Do we need to restart any service after updated to `-1` ?

Comment: You can check if the change took place by `php -i | grep memory_limit`.

Comment: I did that, it showed `memory_limit => 256M => 256M`

Comment: `which php` command show diff php version than `php --version` ! I don't which file I should update - please advise.

Comment: Looking at my `/usr/local/` I don't really see that I have the php7 directory. ‍♂️ : https://i.imgur.com/NFrhJJD.png

Comment: How do you come up with that ? Is there a way or command to tell that  ?

Comment: I have no idea why `php --version` show that I have php `7`. In that new dir, you suggested, I still didn't php 7 : https://i.imgur.com/kPHrvNg.png

Comment: Its "common sense". scnr. Its based on knowledge about folder structure on Unix systems and the knowledge about where Homebrew storage location.

Configuration files like the `php.ini` is stored inside `/etc` and Homebrews base folder is `/user/local/`.

Comment: At the end it doesn't matter which version you have installed. You have to find out which is active on the CLI and find its ini file. You can do this with `php -i | grep php.ini`.

Comment: I don't have a strong common sense like you. sorry for that. I still see nothing related to php 7.  I am SO confuse.  nothing is fixed.  : https://i.imgur.com/XOrHkrP.png

Comment: Open the `/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini`, search `memory_limit` and set the value to `-1`. Follow the steps I already described to verify.

Comment: Do I need to restart any service ? result still show 256M, after I changed it to `-1` as you insist. : https://i.imgur.com/7lhXD8m.png

Comment: Depending on your installation. If PHP runs as a service, you have to restart the service.

Comment: I don't know the command to do that. I will just restart my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Set `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` in your terminal when run composer install command.

```
Run COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install instead of composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` in front of php will work, but is not the best solution. Ideally you need to set the `memory_limit` settings to a higher value.

I have installed `php@7.4` with brew and it works fine, however somehow the php.ini being in use is the default one on **mac** and not the one with php@7.4, even tho when I do `php --ini` and `php -v` it points to my brew version.

I fixed the memory issue by increasing the memory_limit in `/etc/php.ini` .. while php --ini tells me that my ini file is in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini`